# Linux kernel option for maintaining functionality upon undock/redock of laptop to a docking station?

Tags: linux, laptop, docking-station, hp-elitebook

I'm trying to compile a custom kernel. At present, here is the data:

Hardware:

- HP EliteBook 8540w
- [HP docking station](http://h10010.www1.hp.com/wwpc/za/en/sm/WF06c/A1-329290-329229-347699-347699-4017290-4017557.html)

Arch Linux default kernel behavior:

- with computer docked, usb mounse plugged into dock works on boot
- *if undocked/redocked mouse works*

Custom kernel behavior:

- with computer docked, usb mounse plugged into dock works on boot
- *if undocked/redocked mouse no longer works*

Where would I be able to track down the specific module/config option that allows me to regain port functionality with the docking station upon undock/redock? I could start with the default config and do trial and error, but I'm hoping it's simpler than that...